# Most possible outs on river. And you are behind

Tags: odds

Title says it all.

What is the most possible outs on the river?
And you are behind.

With example cards please - not just a number.

Comment: "Are you behind" ... does it make sense to talk about outs when you are not behind?  It's definitely possible to be ahead and not be the favorite to win the hand (e.g. heads-up have < 50%)

Comment: @Michael Does it hurt to clarify you are behind?  If you can be ahead and not be the favorite to the hand then prove it with an answer behind has 24 or more outs.

Comment: Similar question would be having the best chance of winning after the flop yet not having the best hand... wonder if it's worth asking, the best I've seen is 60% chance of winning without having the best hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for the most outs whilst needing to improve, it's 25:

Hero 
6⋄7⋄

Villain 2⋄2♥

Board 4♥4⋄5⋄9♣

8 diamonds

6 overpair outs (6 or 7)

6 straight outs

5 counterfeit outs (5 or 9)

= 25 outs

Comment: You can add one by not giving the villain a diamond

Comment: Nope - If they have 2c/s, the 2d gives them a boat.

Comment: I don't think that can be beat.  I will give it a few days before a check.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

Hero 
9♥9⋄

Villain 2♠6♣

Board 2♥6♥7⋄8♥

9 hearts
3 fives
3 tens
2 sevens
3 eights
2 nines

22 total
Almost 1:1

## Option 2

Hero 
8⋄9⋄

Villain 3♠3♣

Board 6♥6⋄7⋄J♣

8 diamonds flush (3 makes boat for villain)
3 fives straight
3 sevens  counterfeit
3 eights  top pair
3 nines top pair
3 tens straight
2 jacks counterfeit

25 total
with 43 cards remaining
the hand behind is 1.3 : 1 favorite

## Option 3

Hero 
8⋄9⋄

Villain 5♠5♣

Board 6♥6⋄7⋄J♣

9 diamonds flush (5 straight flush)
0 fives
3 sevens  counterfeit
3 eights  top pair
3 nines top pair
3 tens straight
2 jacks counterfeit

23 total